# Select and Replace an embedded style with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to select and replace an embedded styles background path with jQuery? I'm having trouble getting this to work.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function($) {

function myReplaceFunc() {
    var $str = $('style'); 
    $str.replace('wcsstore', 'mytest');
}

myReplaceFunc();

});
</script>

<style>
#test{
background: url("/wcsstore/***/en_GB/images/suppliershop/ecomheader.jpg");
}
</style>

<section id="test">Test 1</section>
<section id="test2">Test 2</section>
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: try directly change background using `$('#test').css('background-image','url(path to image)');`

Comment: if you want to simply set background to some element you can directly use `$('#idOfElement').css('background-image','path to image'');` also what you are doing in wrong as selecting background of style div

Comment: @wpcoder that is not a valid value for background image that requires `"url(....)"` format

Comment: fixed, thanks @charlietfl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.text()` chained to `jQuery()` to get, set the `.textContent` of the element

```
$str.text($str.text().replace('wcsstore', 'mytest'));
```

Comment: Thank you this  worked perfectly.

To address the other commenters it wasn't possible for me to target individual classes to apply the fix and this is not for production use. This is a piece of code to be placed in the header of a template file to alter a multititude of paths for testing purposes on a staging website.

Comment: Just to update I noticed that when executing this code it is doubling up the styles of everything being processed. For example for every element where there is only one style declared it has duplicated that 4x (overwriting over overwrites). Is there any way to prevent this from happening as on the larger pages it is causing a huge delay to process.

Comment: @user6583984 What is the actual code that you are trying? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: There are several approaches available for adjusting CSS. It is difficult to determine the appropriate solution where the actual code and requirement are not included at text of the Question. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the issue with calling `replace()` on a jQuery object, your approach to this is flawed. While it's possible to amend the content of `<style>` tags with JS, it's very far from the best solution.

Instead, you should set the `background-image` on the element directly using the `css()` method. You can provide a function to this method which receives the current value as an argument. You can then call `replace()` on that - as you currently are - to update the value. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  function myReplaceFunc() {
    $('#test').css('background-image', function(i, bg) {
      return bg.replace('wcsstore', 'mytest');
    });
  }

  myReplaceFunc();
});
```

```css
#test {
  background: url("/wcsstore/***/en_GB/images/suppliershop/ecomheader.jpg");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="test">Test 1</section>
<section id="test2">Test 2</section>
```

Comment: @guest271314 possible conflicts such as a class that also contains same search term

Comment: @guest271314 Hacking around CSS as a string isn't a practical solution - the same as you shouldn't with HTML. It opens a lot of points of failure with duplicate/partial matches etc. In addition it also ties the OP to having a `<style>` element within the DOM of the page, which also should be avoided. CSS should be loaded from an external file through a `<link>` element so that it can be minified/bundled and cached.

Comment: _"very far from the best solution."_ Given code at OP, why?

Comment: @charlietfl Not given code at Question. There are several available approaches which could be utilized to achieve expected result. OPs selected option being one, the issue is chaining `.replace()` to `jQuery()` instead of chaining and setting at `.text()`, and possibly the `RegExp`

Comment: `Not given code at Question. There are several available approaches which could be utilized to achieve expected result` exactly my point. There are lots of ways this can be done - however replacing the text of the `<style>` leaves *a lot* of ways it can be broken. It's fragile code, and inherently a less than ideal solution.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan If we insert additional requirements in to the actual Question, your evaluation of the procedure might be accurate from different perspectives. Though OP does not ask for an "ideal" solution, rather asks _"Is it possible to select and replace an embedded styles"_. There is no issue with code at Question other than omission of `.text()`, a `RegExp` could be used for an exact match of the string at the CSS value.

Comment: I get what you're saying, but if someone is asking a question about a flawed solution, then I believe it's our job as educators to correct them. Give them a better solution. If you just give someone bad code because it's what they asked for, then they learn nothing - and worse still, anyone visiting the question in the future believes that the solution which was offered is a valid one which should be used.

Comment: The solution is not "flawed". That is a matter of opinion. Why stop there? We could go further and state that jQuery is not necessary for such a task; and set the value at the `CSSStyleSheet` itself.

Comment: It's very flawed, and honestly I'm a little intrigued that you cannot see why that is.

Answer (score 0):

**1- get the background image url from css applied**

```
var bg = $('#test').css('background-image');
        bg = bg.replace('url(','').replace(')','').replace(/\"/gi, "");
```

**2- change the url**

```
var new_url = bg.replace('wcsstore','mytest');
```

**3- replace the url**

```
$('#test').css('background-image', 'url(' + new_url + ')');
```